# how to add targeting_specs parameter to this facebook graph request (android)

Tags: android, facebook, api

I have been working on facebook graph request for

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/
```

The only problem i am facing is that how to add targeting_specs parameter to this :

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{ad-account-id}/reachestimate",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I have tried with bundle but it gives error that

> json encode is required